# $location.path() not working with Angular routes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I realize there are several posts on here regarding this issue. I have tried them all at this point and is probably why code looks pretty bad at this point. What I am trying to do appears quite simple. On submit of a form, I want to redirect to another view via Angular's routing.

**THIS IS CALLED FROM THE FORM SUBMIT FUNCTION**

```
$http.post('/api/brackets', jsonData, { headers: headers })

   .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
   $scope.brackets = data;
   $scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(next, current) { 
       $console.log('$routeChangeStart', arguments);
      });
   $location.path('/leaderboard').replace(); ///this is where I am trying to redirecto    to
 $scope.apply().replace();
 $location.path('');                        
})
```

****THIS IS IN THE ROUTE PROVIDER****

```
angular.module('appRoutes', []).config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',       function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

 // Enable pushState in routes.
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
$routeProvider

    // home page
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/signin.html',
        controller: 'authController'
    })
    .when('/signin', {
        templateUrl: 'views/signin.html',
        controller: 'authController'
    })
    .when('/signup', {
        templateUrl: 'views/signup.html',
        controller: 'authController'
    })

    .when('/dash', {
        templateUrl: 'views/dashboard.html',
        controller: 'dashController'
    })
    .when('/test', {
        templateUrl: 'views/test.html',
        controller: IndexCtrl
    })
    .when('/profile', {
        templateUrl: 'views/profile.ejs',
        controller: IndexCtrl
    })
    .when('/leaderboard', {
        templateUrl: 'views/leaderboard.html',
        controller: 'leaderboardController' // we might want to make this a partial
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });

//$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

}]);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: your .apply() should be .$apply()

Answer (score 0):

```
$http.post('/api/brackets', jsonData, { headers: headers })
.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.brackets = data;
    $scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(next, current) { 
        $console.log('$routeChangeStart', arguments);
    });
    $location.path('/leaderboard').replace(); ///this is where I am trying to redirecto    to
    $scope.apply().replace();
    $location.path('');                        
})
```

This looks really off to me, first you're telling the $location.path to go to /leaderboard, but then two lines later you're telling it to go to nowhere. Do you instead mean to do this:

```
$http.post('/api/brackets', jsonData, { headers: headers })
.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.brackets = data;
    $scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(next, current) { 
        $console.log('$routeChangeStart', arguments);
    });
    $location.path('/leaderboard');              
})
```

Why are you doing an $apply? Also, why are you doing a .replace?

Comment: The locatation.path(''); is a typo. that is not in my code. I did the apply and replace because of of the other posts on here with the same issue suggested that and it worked. However it didn't work for me.

Comment: Regarding your question of understanding the code above...again based on another post, someone was saying that this would be a way to check via the console whether the route change is even registering.

Comment: You'll have to be more specific with what your code is, for all intents and purposes it should be working.

Comment: The http post is wrapped inside an onSubmit function for a form which inserts a json doc into mongoDB and then should redirect to /leaderboard which is one of the routes listed. That is not working. What other specifics would point to a possible issue? Thanks.